# Which t-test to use to test significance between two means

Tags: statistics

I have a data set containing calcium concentrations of groundwater in 2013 and 2014 at a specific site. Sample size is NOT the same (n = 10 in 2013, n = 13 in 2014)

I want to test if there are significant changes in the means of groundwater calcium concentrations between the two years.

Surely I must use a t-test but I am not sure if I need to use paired or unpaired because I don't know whether to conclude my data is independent or dependent of each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be paired if there were a 13 identifiable sections at the site. Also, 10 sections were measured in 2013; all 13 were measured in 2014, and you can match up
the the data for the 10 sections that were measured both times. From the
way you describe the situation, that structure seems unlikely. You mention
the possibility of observations from 2014 being somehow correlated with
those from 2013, but that makes sense only if there is paired structure by
which each particular measurement in one year can be linked with one
particular measurement in the other. The fact that you have 10 in one year
and 13 in the other year makes that seem unlikely. If there is no such pairwise
linkage then you have two-sample data.

I recommend you do a Welch (separate-variances) two-sample t test. The
formula for the test statistic is

$$T = \frac{\bar X_{13}-\bar X_{14}}{\sqrt{\frac{S_{13}^2}{10}+\frac{S_{14}^2}{13}}}.$$
The degrees of freedom $\nu$ are given by a (moderately messy) formula you can find on [*this Wikipedia page*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test), where
$9 \le \nu \le 21.$ [Roughly speaking, $\nu$ will be closer to 21 if the two
sample variances are nearly equal and nearer to 9 if they are substantially different.]

*Notes:* (1) This is the form of the 2-sample t test you should use unless you are sure that the variance of the measurements cannot have changed from 2013 to 2014.

(2) Any t test assumes that the data are nearly normal. Warning signs of 
 troublesome departure from normal data would be severely skewed data for one (or both) of the years, especially if there are several outliers  in the same direction from the mean. (Other two-sample tests can be used if data are not normal.)

(3) If you are not confident that conditions for a t test are met, I can take a look.
You could edit the data into your question and leave me a Comment. (Preferably
list the measurements for each year along a row, values separated by commas.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It makes sense that different n in two groups cannot qualify for paired t test. I tested for variance in R and found that p value was > 0.05, so safe to same that my data has equal variance. I am going to carry on with welch two-sample t test assuming equal variances.

Comment: Not a good idea to use variance test as a criterion to decide between pooled and Welch two-sample t. The variance test has horrible power, especially when sample sizes are as low as yours. Best just always to use Welch, except when you 'know' for some reason that variances must be equal.

Comment: Thank you. I will just use Welch then.

Comment: Hi Bruce, Sorry I had another question. I am doing a test on another data set and in one population group the data is normally distributed, in the other it is not. I log-transformed both data and then conducted the t-test. Do I need to convert the p-value reported in the log-transformed t-test back to original or it has an interpretation? Thanks

Comment: Can't say without seeing the data. Inappropriate to chat in Comments. Perhaps we can close out this question and you can start a new one, so all can be aware of the new question.